# Why is a $\frac{kT}{2}$ correction required to bandgap data?

Tags: experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics

An LED was cooled in a cryostat and the spectra measured at different temperatures. Plotting intensity vs current allowed us to find the energy at peak intensity, which we equate to the bandgap. Then plotting these energies (bandgaps) against temperature we compared our results to the Varshni equation. To make out results agree with the theory, a $\frac{kT}{2}$ correction was required. Why is this correction necessary?

Comment: Would you be willing to post your data plots, with and without the correction?